# node: 1: This: not found

Tags: anchor, node.js

I am trying to set up the solana development environment on my WSL, I followed [this](https://solana.com/developers/guides/getstarted/local-rust-hello-world) tutorial. When I run `anchor test` I get the following error:

```
Error: websocket error
/mnt/c/Users/faceb/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: 1: This: not found
```

- node --version: v20.11.1
- which node: /usr/bin/node

I guess I am missing something. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that `yarn` was missing, `anchor test` depends on it, so the error. After installing it globally, like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the example you are referring to is a native program, if you want to use the anchor framework better follow this guide:

https://www.anchor-lang.com/docs/installation

and do the hello world there.

Comment: Thanks, but why does anchor take the windows node path instead the wsl one?

Comment: I tried to `anchor init a_random_name` and I get the same error.